# replacing text on jpg files in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have folder which has jpg images continuously taken from a camera and the jpg are in this format.

```
1UYK08HJ_20140403165858071_SYPTE1-PC.jpg 
1YK0BHJX_20140403165902791_SYPTE1-PC.jpg
1YK08HJX_20140403165959270_SYPTE1-PC.jpg
IDYKDBH_20140403170236634_SYPTE1-PC.jpg
```

I am trying to replace the text from SYPTE1-PC to SHEFFIELD  I am running this script it runs first time perfectly but when i try to run the same script  again it does not work on other newly created images. I have used a third party  helper batch file called repl.bat.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

```
@echo off
dir *.jpg /b /a-d |find /i /v "%~nx0" |find /i /v "repl.bat" |repl "(.*?_)(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(...).*(\..*)" "ren \q$&\q \q$1SHEFFIELD_$2_$3_$4-$5_$6_$7_$8$9\q" xa >"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\export\renfiles.bat"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.JPG) do (
set $file="%%a"
ren "%%a" "!$file:SYPTE1-PC=SHEFFIELD!"
echo File [%%a] Done)
```

:EDIT

For more option you can do like this :

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.JPG) do (
set $file="%%a"
set $file="!$file:SYPTE1-PC=SHEFFIELD!"
set $file="!$file:SYPTE=SHEFFIELD!"
ren "%%a" "!$file!"
echo File [%%a] Done)
```

EDIT 2

The method to separate : 20140403165858071 in 2014_04_03_16_58_58_071

```
@echo off&cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /b/a-d *.JPG') do (
echo %%a %%b %%c %%d
set $Char=%%b
set $CharF=!$Char:~0,4!_!$Char:~4,2!_!$Char:~6,2!_!$Char:~8,2!_!$Char:~10,2!_!$Char:~12,2!_!$Char:~14!
echo !$CharF!
pause)
```

You can then adjust yourself the `REN` with `%%a_!$CharF!_%%c_%%d` or the way you want it

Comment: thanks sachadee . is it possible to look for more option like SYPTE1-PC OR SYPTE.

Comment: What do you mean with more option ?

Comment: Thanks a lot .. can u tell me if this possible to do ..20140403165858071 = 2014_04_03_16_58_58_071. the date time format..