# change datetime text on files

Tags: batch-file

I have this format  on jpg files  but i need the time and date like this which I am not able to get this.

present format

```
1UYK08HJ_20140403165858071_SYPTE1-PC.jpg 
1YK0BHJX_20140403165902791_SYPTE1-PC.jpg
1YK08HJX_20140403165959270_SYPTE1-PC.jpg
IDYKDBH_20140403170236634_SYPTE1-PC.jpg
```

required format is

```
1UYK08HJ_SYPTE1-PC_2014_04_03_16_58_58_071.jpg 
1YK0BHJX_SYPTE1-PC_2014_04_03_16_59_02_791.jpg
1YK08HJX_SYPTE1-PC_2014_04_03_16_59_59_270.jpg
IDYKDBH_SYPTE1-PC_2014_04_03_17_02_36_634.jpg
```

my query is :

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\export" || exit /b
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_." %%A in ('dir /b /a-d *_*.jpg') do (
  Echo ren %%A_%%B_%%C.%%D %%A_%%C_%%B.%%D
)
popd
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912016/replacing-text-on-jpg-files-in-a-folder/22912338#22912338

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method to separate : 20140403165858071 in 2014_04_03_16_58_58_071

```
    @echo off&cls
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /b/a-d *.JPG') do (
    set $Char=%%b
    set $CharF=!$Char:~0,4!_!$Char:~4,2!_!$Char:~6,2!_!$Char:~8,2!_!$Char:~10,2!_!$Char:~12,2!_!$Char:~14!
    echo !$CharF!
    pause)
```

You can then adjust yourself the `REN` with `%%a_!$CharF!_%%c_%%d` or the way you want it